# Criar base de dados e usuário MongoDB via shell

Tags: sql, mongodb, ssh

Preciso criar base de dados e usuário do MongoDB, porém tudo via shell.

Encontrei algo sobre --eval e --shell, porém não consegui fazer funcionar, estou tentando dessa forma:

`mongo mongodb://11.11.123.321:27017 --eval "db.createUser({user: "teste", pwd: "teste123", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "novaBase"}]})"`

Lógico que se eu executar o comando inicial der um enter e depois executar o segundo vai dar certo, mas o cenário atual eu preciso fazer tudo isso "de uma vez só", com uma lib ssh que conecta no servidor e executa o comando, faço isso com o mysql já exemplo:

`mysql -u root -pteste123 -e "CREATE USER teste@localhost"........`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, como você não postou o erro retornado, é difícil ter certeza, mas acredito que o problema é que o delimitador do seu comando são aspas duplas, que são utilizadas no próprio comando.

Experimenta executar com aspas simples assim:

```
mongo mongodb://11.11.123.321:27017 --eval 'db.createUser({user: "teste", pwd: "teste123", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "novaBase"}]})'
```

Se não funcionar, compartilha o erro para podermos te ajudar melhor.